# How do we access the variables set inside the tox environment again in another block of the tox?

Tags: shell, tox

I am using tox-docker and it sets POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT as an environment variable. How do I access this env variable again? I want to do this because I have to provide this to the pytest command.

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True
envlist = py37-django22

[testenv]
docker = postgres:9
dockerenv =
    POSTGRES_USER=asd
    POSTGRES_DB=asd
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD=asd

setenv =
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.base

deps=-rrequirements.txt
     -rrequirements_dev.txt

commands =
    env
    python -c "print('qweqwe', {env:POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT:'default_port'})"
    pytest -sv --postgresql-port={env:POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT:} --cov-report html --cov-report term --cov=app -l --tb=long {posargs} --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml
```

here, POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT is set by the tox-docker. but when I try to access it inside tox it is not available. But when I execute the env command inside tox it prints the variable.

```
py37-django22 docker: run 'postgres:9'
py37-django22 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='480168593'
py37-django22 run-test: commands[0] | env
PATH=
TOX_WORK_DIR=src/.tox
HTTPS_PROXY=http://0000:8000
LANG=C
HTTP_PROXY=http://0000:8000
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.base
PYTHONHASHSEED=480168593
TOX_ENV_NAME=py37-django22
TOX_ENV_DIR=/.tox/py37-django22
POSTGRES_USER=swordfish
POSTGRES_DB=swordfish
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=swordfish
POSTGRES_HOST=172.17.0.1
POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT=32822
POSTGRES_5432_TCP=32822
VIRTUAL_ENV=.tox/py37-django22
py37-django22 run-test: commands[1] | python -c 'print('"'"'qweqwe'"'"', '"'"'default_port'"'"')'
qweqwe default_port
py37-django22 run-test: commands[2] | pytest -sv --postgresql-port= --cov-report html --cov-report term --cov=app -l --tb=long --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml
```

Comment: welcome Groot221 :)  You may want to add "shell" to your tags for more visibility.

Comment: What would be the result if you had the following commands instead? `python -c "import os; print('qweqwe', os.environ['POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT'])"` and `pytest -sv --postgresql-port=${POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT}`

Comment: Hi @sinoroc '''python -c "import os; print('qweqwe', os.environ['POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT'])" ''' provides the right output but again '''pytest -sv --postgresql-port=${POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT}''' fails. I just assigned the variable used by my app in the setenv section in this way -- '''APP_DB_PORT=$POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT ''' and my app directly picks up the port number. I removed the --postgresql-port flag from the command.

Comment: I guess it should have worked then. Maybe using the [`passenv` configuration option](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-passenv) could help.

Answer (score 0):

If a script sets an environment variable, that envvar is visible to that process only. If it exports the variable, the variable will be visible whatever sub-shells that script may spawn. Once the script exits, all envvars set by the shell process and any child processes will be gone since they existed only in that memory space.

Not sure what you're trying to do, Docker is not my speciality, but 5432 is the common Postgres port. If you're trying to supply it to pytest, you could say

`POSTGRES_5432_TCP_PORT=5432 pytest <test_name>`

Or something to that effect.

Comment: Hi @ether_joe , thank you for answering. I have updated the post, maybe it might help.